# Admin Menu is messed up - Drupal 6 (Not cache related)

Tags: 6

Here is a screenshot of the menu on our dev server, everything looks fine:

[image]
View it bigger here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVtpo.png

Here is a screenshot of the menu on production, not fine:
[image]
View it bigger here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZqGh.png

I cleared the cache a couple of times, not sure why it all of a sudden started happening.

This site has also had issues where the main nav menu disappears from time to time. Clearing the cache restores it and it may not be related to this issue at all, but thought I would mention it.

[Admin Menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module 6.x-1.5

Comment: Have you got ads or other external Javascript on the live site? Often such problems are caused by scripts injecting broken HTML into the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under admin/settings/admin_menu there is a feature to Wipe and Rebuild. That fixed the issue for me.

Very weird problem.